# How to force error when one container doesn't depend on another one?

Tags: docker-compose, healthcheck

I have the following config:

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: ../rishat_stripe_2402_django/django.Dockerfile
      context: ../rishat_stripe_2402_django
    env_file:
      - .env_docker_compose
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.docker_compose
      - WSGI_MODULE=config.wsgi_docker_compose
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate --settings=$$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE; python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=$$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE; gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 $$WSGI_MODULE:application"
    volumes:
      - static_django:/root/rishat_stripe/static/
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env_docker_compose
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ../rishat_stripe_2402_nginx/nginx.Dockerfile
      context: ../rishat_stripe_2402_nginx
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS=http://backend:8000
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - static_django:/home/nginx_user/rishat_nginx/django_static/
  stripe:
    image: stripe/stripe-cli:latest
    env_file:
      - .env_docker_compose
    command: listen --forward-to backend:8000/webhook/ --api-key $$STRIPE_SECRET_API_KEY

volumes:
  pg_data:
  static_django:
```

Sometimes, when I do `docker compose up`, it gives error that is caused by backend service launched before db service and cannot connect to it, but **only sometimes**

I know that in order to resolve the issue I need to healthcheck db service as stated [here](https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck) and add

```
depends_on:
  db:
    service_healthy
```

to `backend` service.

But I am not guranteed that this does what it says, because I don't know if the issue occurs which causes the error. In other words, if there is the same error: `backend` starts before `db` I cannot recreate it to check the config (the error happens only sometimes)

Thank you